# Office interop with Office 2010 virtualized versions

Tags: c#, ms-office, com-interop

We have C# interop code that does the following:

```
_currentApplication = (MSWord._Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
```

which works fine for most .msi based installs of Office. This code now fails on Office installs that are run as "click-to-install" such as the Student and Home edition. Installing the Office 2010 PIAs doesn't help.

Does anyone know if COM interop can be made to work in this situation?